# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable while storing data in SQlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

This is the code where I'm getting an Error

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.store_db(item) #--> at this line
    print('pipeline :' + item['caseno'])
    return item

def store_db(self,item):
    self.curr.execute("""insert into case_details values (?,?,?)"""(
        item['caseno'][0],
        item['party'][0],
        item['corr'][0]
        ))
    self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after the query.

Comment: Hey Buddy, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: No worries, brother.